# How can I generate a windows DLL with pyInstaller?

Tags: python, python-2.6, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build a DLL file with PyInstaller. I read all the documentation, but still could not generate a dll.

Sorry, I may be asking you something obvious, but even so, I ask you to help me if you can.

So far I can generate the "dist" and "buil" folders with various files, including an exe.

Comment: are you sure pyinstaller can build dll's? can you point us to some supporting docs? (+1 all the same because Im interested in the answer)

Comment: Thanks @JoranBeasley. According to the pyInstaller's own documentation, yes, it can. 
http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/ # installing-pyinstaller

Comment: are you talking about the `-r option` ? that is for including additional dll dependencies not for generating ..

Comment: The documentation says something about writing my own dll. But I'm not sure I understand what that means. http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#dll

Comment: I got this `You will need to write your own dll, but thanks to Allan Green for refactoring the C code and making that a managable task.` ... its about including dll's that you can reference in your python script ... Im pretty sure that this is just not possible with pyinstaller ... I think you might need to look at Cython to create dlls   (see http://wolfprojects.altervista.org/articles/dll-in-c-for-python/)

Comment: @JoranBeasley, I know the Cython project. But what I would like to write the dll entirely in python. What Cython offers is not it. But... Guess I'll have to finish writing my dll in this project. Thank you anyway your time spent and help. :)